# Is there any way to get my scrollback history of terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, cat

Is there any way to get my **scrollback history of the terminal** (not only a history of the terminal but also **the file's data that I viewed in terminal using CAT command**)??
I want to get the file data that I  viewed using CAT command in terminal but now the *file is deleted from my system.*

Comment: There is no scroll history stored by the OS. Once the terminal is closed the history goes with it.

Comment: This is why you need complete daily backups.  Utilities like `rsnapshot`, `ccollect`, make this easy.

Comment: Did you edit the file recently?  If so, which editor do you use?  There is a chance that your editor stored a hidden backup file.

Comment: If the data is still available in the terminal emulator's scrollback buffer, use copy and paste.